# How to add attribute to DOM element?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular8

I need to add attribute `multiple` to element:

```
 <mat-select [formControlName]="field.name" multiple>
```

But add this by condition:

I have tried:

```
  <mat-select
    [formControlName]="field.name" multiple
    [attr.multiple]="field?.multiple ? 'multiple' : ''"
  >
```

It gives me `multiple="multiple"`

But I need:

```
 <mat-select [formControlName]="field.name" multiple>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [mat-select](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api) has an `multiple` boolean @Input, so you should use it like this:

```
<mat-select
  [formControlName]="field.name" multiple
  [multiple]="!!field?.multiple"
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-example-xiyykp?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

```
<mat-select [formControlName]="field.name" [multiple]="field?.multiple">
```

Comment: Check the modified answer

Comment: Unknown property multiple,

Comment: Check the demo.